# Running Javascript files (.js)

Tags: script, javascript

I've noticed that if you try and **run** (not edit) a Javascript file, instead of going to edit.  It will come up with an error.  This error normally sounds like it is missing a reference (your code, not the program running your code).  I getting stuff like this:

> Script:  \h0700sdc01\home$\etc.
>
> Line:    3
> Char:    1
>
> Error:   'document' is undefined'
>
> Code:    800A1391
>
> Source:  Microsoft JScript runtime error

Is this normal?  If it doesn't error, then it does nothing.  My question is, is it trying to execute it like a program (similar to VBScript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the javascript has references to the HTML document object model (DOM), then you will have problems running it like it is a VBScript. This is because the script is designed to perform operations on an HTML document within a web browser.

Comment: Are you implying that JavaScript can be run on its own?  Can I run it as a separate *program*?  If so, could you provide me with a reference on the subject (more in depth details)?  Just points for now :)

Comment: It would be possible to run javascript on it's own, however you will have to refer to Microsoft's documentation on what all javascript can/cannot do/access in the OS. Most of my familiarity with javascript is within web pages.

Comment: @XanderLamkins JS outside the browser environment is most commonly executed using the Node.js runtime: https://nodejs.org.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same "error" as you. This message box is run by VBScript. This is  completely normal. This is only because the operating system thinks it is a system file and tries to run it. If you want to edit it, you can select the default program to open the file. Change it from Microsoft Windows Based Script Host to notepad or a text editor. That should open it.
Hope this helped!